# HTML encoding settings in Firefox

Tags: browser, encoding

Whenever I open [the Jargon File site](http://catb.org/esr/jargon/html/index.html) the encoding is wrong.

See [@-Party](http://catb.org/esr/jargon/html/0/at-party.html) entry.

Every page sets it to "ISO-8859-1" but that doesn't seem to work. Setting the view to "Western" (which is "ISO-8859-1" actually) manually does the trick.

Any idea what's going on? This happens in both IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file on the server is br0ked.

Html-verification:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcatb.org%2Fesr%2Fjargon%2Fhtml%2F0%2Fat-party.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

**Update**

Since the original answer did not satisfy your curiosity and because my own was marginally intrigued, I looked at the file and found that there is a non-printable "M- " character in there that would [correspond to character 223](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/107568-printing-non-printing-characters-%5E-m-notation.html)

Here is how I found it:

[image: char 223]

Basically, whoever wrote that document made a boo-boo when they processed the file with some tool or whatever. By that I mean they introduced a non-printable character into a text file.

Comment: But why doesn't Firefox use the correct encoding?

Comment: Because it thinks the file is utf8 or something due to that weird character which it detects to be non iso 8859 1. ***  (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified Character Encoding). ***

Comment: Is there a way to tell Firefox to use the encoding specified no matter its own thoughts about the affair?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the inner workings of character encoding detection in Firefox or otherwise.